# Bulk Folder Rename

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to get a shell script to go through a directory and rename the sub-directories (depth of 1). Basically, I'm looking for it to show the current directory name and prompt me for the name to change it to. To further specify, some of the folders will not need to be renamed, so I'm also looking for a way to skip a folder. I'm thinking something like an

```
#! /bin/bash

for dname in ./*/; do
        echo $dname
        echo What would you like the new name to be?
        read newdname   
        mv "./$dname" "./$newdname"
done
```

But that doesn't include skipping folders. I'm thinking it needs an 'if' statement to allow me to enter 'skip' at the prompt to skip the folder.

Comment: Replace `mv` by `mv -i`.

Comment: If your directory contains a file called `bee`, you will loose your question mark. If unsure use quotes. Also never pass variables to commands without quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the question? Do you want to know how to write the if statement? Probably like this:

```
if [[ $newdname != skip ]] ; then
    mv "./$dname" "./$newdname"
fi
```

Or do you want to know whether it's a good idea? It probably isn't, as there might be a need to name a directory 'skip'. Using an empty string as a "skip" makes more sense, as you can't rename a directory to an emtpy name. In such situation, change the condition to `if [[ $newdname ]]`.

Comment: That did it. I'm using skip because I won't have a folder called skip in this particular example, so no problem.